# Beginner Java project: what is wrong with my Array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

I have just started learning Java as part of my university course and am having a problem with y first project. I am just starting to create a project that basically sorts coins. I am trying to make a method called printCoinList() that prints the contents of a coin list, indicating what denominations are currently in circulation (i.e "The current coin denominations are in circulation: 200,100,50,20,10), in pennies.

So far I have declared my instance fields, created a parameter and attempted to make this method. My only issue is when i try and test it in the main() method it seems to have a problem with me using an array as the coinList parameter. This is what I have so far:

```
public class CoinSorter {

    //Instance Fields
    String currency;
    int minCoinIn;
    int maxCoinIn;
    int[] coinList;
    
    //constructor
    public CoinSorter(String Currency, int minValueToExchange, int maxValueToExchange, int[] initialCoinList) {
        currency=Currency;
        minCoinIn=minValueToExchange;
        maxCoinIn = maxValueToExchange;
        coinList= initialCoinList;
        
    }
    
                public void printCoinList() {
        System.out.println("The current coin denominations are in circulation"
                + coinList);
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //An example
        
        CoinSorter exampleOne = new CoinSorter("pounds", 0, 10000, {10,20,50,100,200});
```

The only problems seems to be in exampleOne as when I take this out the rest of the code seems to run fine.
The error message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The constructor CoinSorter(String, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) is undefined
    Syntax error on token "{", delete this token
    Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
```

So does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because an *array initializer* may only be specified at declaration site or as part of an array creation expression. ([JLS § 10.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6))

Below is an array initializer at declaration site.

```java
int[] array = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
```

This is short for

```java
int[] array = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
```

However, it may not be used as 'array literal', unlike a string literal. That means that you must write out the *array creation expression*:

```java
new CoinSorter("pounds", 0, 10000, new int[] { 10, 20, 50, 100, 200 });
```

Comment: Hello thanks! that has worked. I used

new CoinSorter("pounds", 0, 10000, new int[] { 10, 20, 50, 100, 200 });

However now when i try to print my method it comes out with 

The current coin denominations are in circulation[I@1c4af82c

Instead of printting the coin denominations, it just prints the memory. Any idea how to fix this as well? Thanks very much!

Comment: @Millyfg That question is already [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array).

Comment: Thank you! all sorted.

Comment: @Millyfg Don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted, to let the community know that this question has been addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in java can be declared/initialized using one of the following ways.

```
int[] myIntArray = {10,20,50,100,200};
int[] myIntArray = new int[]{10,20,50,100,200};
```

replace       `CoinSorter exampleOne = new CoinSorter("pounds", 0, 10000, {10,20,50,100,200});`

with

```
  CoinSorter exampleOne = new CoinSorter("pounds", 0, 10000, myIntArray );
```

OR

```
   CoinSorter exampleOne = new CoinSorter("pounds", 0, 10000, new int[]{10,20,50,100,200});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firt of all , in java , you need to specify the type of your Array :

CoinSorter exampleOne = new CoinSorter("pounds", 0, 10000, new int[]{10,20,50,100,200});

Then your "printCoinList" method will not work as excepted , this should print :

The current coin denominations are in circulation [I@7852e922

Your final code should be :

import java.util.Arrays;

public class CoinSorter {

```
//Instance Fields
String currency;
int minCoinIn;
int maxCoinIn;
int[] coinList;

//constructor
public CoinSorter(String Currency, int minValueToExchange, int maxValueToExchange, int[] initialCoinList) {
    currency=Currency;
    minCoinIn=minValueToExchange;
    maxCoinIn = maxValueToExchange;
    coinList= initialCoinList;
    
}

            public void printCoinList() {
    System.out.println("The current coin denominations are in circulation : "
            + Arrays.toString(coinList));
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    //An example
    CoinSorter exampleOne = new CoinSorter("pounds", 0, 10000, new int[]{10,20,50,100,200});
    exampleOne.printCoinList();
    
}
```

}

Result :
The current coin denominations are in circulation : [10, 20, 50, 100, 200]

Good luck :) I hope I could access to you future exchange  and buy and hold some crypto :D

Answer (score 0):

before creating an object `CoinSorter exampleOne = new CoinSorter("pounds", 0, 10000, {10,20,50,100,200});` declare and initialize an array `int arr[]={10,20,50,100,200}`and then pass it in the constructor rather than passing `{10,20,50,100,200}`

like this

```
int arr[]={10,20,50,100,200};
CoinSorter exampleOne = new CoinSorter("pounds", 0, 10000, arr);
```